# vue js new object elements are not rendered. when using v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

using vue js and vuetify, I use this Method to add elements to an object

```
validate () {
        var element = {}
        element.name = this.name
        element.calories = 100            
        this.items.push(element);
      }
```

This is my Template:

```
<v-col
              v-for="item in props.items"
              :key="item.name"
              cols="12"
              sm="6"
              md="4"
              lg="3"
            >
<-- ... >
<v-btn
      :disabled="!valid"
      color="success"
      class="mr-4"
      @click="validate"
    >
```

The thing is, when I push new elements, they are not rendered. I have this in codepen: https://codepen.io/averied/pen/wvKXrBB?editors=1010

Comment: Your code has two `methods` objects. You already have a `methods` object near the end of the script, that's where you need to add the `validate` method. (I found this because the browser's console showed errors for the buttons' click handlers)

Comment: you're right, and after fixing this the codepen example is working correctly; however, exactly the same code is not working in my test environment. I'm jest locally testing with ````npm run serve